# Hive Mapreduce Jobs failing

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hbase

I am new to hive, hbase and hadoop.

In a single machine I managed to run all three of them.

Successfull created a table in hbase and integrated that table in Hive

If I do

```
SELECT * FROM UserLog
```

I can view all the information that are stored via hbase.

But when I run

```
SELECT tag FROM UserLog
```

I get a big chunck of errors and warnings which is beyond my capabilities of understanding.

```
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop-2.3.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hbase-0.98.0-hadoop2/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /usr/local/hadoop-2.3.0/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0 which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
14/05/02 12:37:45 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
14/05/02 12:37:45 WARN conf.Configuration: file:/tmp/root/hive_2014-05-02_12-37-39_720_753036204496452322-1/-local-10003/jobconf.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.retry.interval;  Ignoring.
14/05/02 12:37:45 WARN conf.Configuration: file:/tmp/root/hive_2014-05-02_12-37-39_720_753036204496452322-1/-local-10003/jobconf.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.attempts;  Ignoring.
Execution log at: /tmp/root/root_20140502123737_5566ca5c-5e3e-4add-b8b9-d74c25369d20.log
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9000/usr/local/hbase-0.98.0-hadoop2/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1116)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:288)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:224)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestamps(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestampsAndCacheVisibilities(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1285)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1282)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1282)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:562)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:557)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecDriver.execute(ExecDriver.java:420)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecDriver.main(ExecDriver.java:740)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
Job Submission failed with exception 'java.io.FileNotFoundException(File does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9000/usr/local/hbase-0.98.0-hadoop2/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar)'
Execution failed with exit status: 1
Obtaining error information

Task failed!
Task ID:
  Stage-1

Logs:

/tmp/root/hive.log
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
```

The file not found error about this `commons-httpclient-3.1.jar` exist in that folder and I set the permission to 777 (just in case).

I use 
Hive 0.13.0
Hbase 0.98.0
Hadoop 2.3.0

Please let me know if you need any more information.

If anyone help me to get over this error will be much appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

How did you set these up? Is this CDH?  IF so a VM or on a real cluster?

I ask because there is a problem in the CDH5 VM that hive can not access required third party libraries - as you have discovered. I have posted to cdh-users mailing list on this and have not received an adequate response yet.

Comment: Yes I am using CDH 5. Not many users are using Hadoop and it clearly shows in the community. Its very difficult to put a cluster up and running. Spent 2 weeks with not credible improvements. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I will report back here if/when I receive info from the cdh-users mailing list on the CDH5 VM issue with hive libraries.